# Series divergence and convergence

Tags: calculus

The series is the sum from $n=1$ to infinity of $\frac {2n}{(8n+11)}$

I know this series diverges by the divergence test because the limit is $\frac 14$ (not zero) but how can I know what it diverges to? is it infinity?

Comment: If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n>0$, then $\sum_{n=1}^Na_n\to+\infty$

Comment: "Divergent" means that it doesn't converge, so it either goes to $\pm\infty$ or oscillates between values.

Comment: @TheCount How can a non-existent object "oscillate between values?"  Do you mean that the sequence of partial sums oscillates between values?

Comment: Does the series move in one direction (positive vs. negative) or does it change directions?  If the series diverges, and it does not change direction, then it must go to...

Comment: @Dr.MV Obviously. This isn't a question from a graduate analysis course, here.

Comment: @TheCount "oscillate between values" may be a problematic intuition. for example take an enumeration $(q_n)_n$ of $\Bbb Q$, then $\sum_{n=1}^N (q_{n+1}-q_n)=q_{N+1}-q_1$ is not really oscillating (but generates a dense set)

Comment: @tofurind It's a perfectly legitimate point, but again, I tried to target my response to the level of the OP, which is clearly not at the level of such concerns yet.

Comment: @TheCount Yes, I were aware of that. ;) My comment were more meant as additional information for the OP not to memorize a maybe wrong interpretation of your comment.

Comment: @tofurind Fair enough, then. :)

Comment: Time to learn how to typeset the math.

Comment: @Dr.MV good comment, although I would have asked what "it" is supposed to be, even though it makes me sound like Bill Clinton.

Comment: @zhw. Wasn't Bill's question regarding what "is" is?  Aside, I had asked you a question in a comment on 19 March regarding a limit that, under certain conditions, was $e^{\int_0^1 \log(f(x))\,dx}$.  Did you receive notification on this?

Comment: I can't believe people trying even to solve this: what is the purpose?

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes, it was "it depends on what the meaning of "is" is" or something close to that. Actually Clinton was probably right on that. Americans laugh at that, but it was probably, legally, a good point. Sorry, I forgot about that integral, will look at it.

Comment: Clinton was gifted in his ability to absorb information quickly and understand complexities.  Remember he was a Yale law graduate.  So, his depth of legal understanding is not surprising.  His wife might surpass him intellectually, but she did not possess his intuitiveness and ability to connect with he "average" person.  On the integral, the issue remaining is whether if $f=0$ on a set of measure $0$ yields the same result as when $f\ne 0$.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2n}{8n+11} = \frac{1}{4}$, therefore the series does not converge. 
To answer your question we need to make two observations: the series is a sum of positive terms, and the sequence $\frac{2n+2}{8n+19}$ is an increasing one. In such a case, the series diverges to positive infinity for its value is arbitrarily large.

To see that $\frac{2n}{8n+11}$ is positive, it is sufficient to observe that n goes from 1 to infinity. 
On the other hand, we also see that $\frac{2n+2}{8n+19}>\frac{2n}{8n+11} \Leftrightarrow (2n+2)(8n+11)-2n(8n+19)>0 \Leftrightarrow 22>0$, thus we have what we aimed for.

Answer (score 0):

One way to investigate the convergence/divergence of a series is to use the comparison test. For this series, one can compare: $\frac{2}{19}=\frac{2n}{19n} \leq \frac{2n}{8n+11} \leq \frac{2n}{8n}=\frac{1}{4}$. Now summing:

$$\sum_{n=1}^ \infty \frac{2}{19} \leq \sum_{n=1}^ \infty \frac{2n}{8n+11} \leq \sum_{n=1}^ \infty \frac{1}{4} \Rightarrow \infty \leq \sum_{n=1}^ \infty \frac{2n}{8n+11} \leq \infty $$

Another way is (mentioned by AlexT above) to see that it is an increasing positive series: $a_n<a_{n+1}.$

Now, here is a challenge for you: Does a decreasing positive series converge: $a_n>a_{n+1}>0$?